# Entity Framework 6 Include() does not really includes the navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties, navigation, include

I have a simple but at the same time an annoying problem. I try to create generic methods for CRUD operations in Business Layer. There is a specific requirement that all navigation properties should be included for some objects and should be returned as a List.

Please look at the both code samples:

```
List<Event> list;
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var dbQuery = db.Set<Event>();
    list = dbQuery.Include(x => x.Location).ToList();
}
```

Above code snippet works fine as expected.

```
List<Event> list;
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var dbQuery = db.Set<Event>();
    // foreach(var np in navigationProperties) -> I omitted this block and only included one property to keep it simple
    dbQuery.Include(x => x.Location);
    list = dbQuery.ToList();
}
```

Above code snippet does not work (was working fine in EF4). The reason why I need the second block is that navigation properties which should always be included are stored in a seperate manifest file and via foreach loop these are included depending on object type.

It seems both are very same but actually not. I could not find a solution and need your help.

Thank you in advance for any comment/feedback.

UPDATE (with SOLUTION): Thanks to Masoud'd feedback, the problem is now clear. if you call dbQuery.Include(...) then the sql command in the dbQuery is NOT changed. Therefore you need to assign the result to another query. I provide the following code which works fine for others who have the same problem:

```
List<Event> list;
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var dbQuery = db.Set<Event>();
    DbQuery<Event> query = null;
    foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
    {
        if(query==null)
            query = dbQuery.Include(navigationProperty);
        else
            query = query.Include(navigationProperty);
    }
    if (query != null) list = query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between 1st and 2nd snippet?

Comment: Does not work?... I think I'll go to my boss today and say it does not work and see if that explanation makes him happy :D

Comment: @Neel: Yes it does not include the "Location" property. I also do not see a difference. It was working fine in EF4.

Comment: @PaulZahra: what do you mean exactly? I am a freelancer and do not have a boss!

Comment: please have a look at [link](http://i59.tinypic.com/2wf1rmq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
{
  ...
  var query = dbQuery.Include(x=>x.Location);
  list = query.ToList();
  ...
}
```

Comment: As I stated the first code snippet already works and you provided the same code. I need to trigger the Include method in a foreach loop and therefore I need to use the second code snippet.

Comment: @IbrahimÇ. My code isn't as your first code snippet, It save the result in an IQueryable variable and then use it, It could use in loop too.

Comment: Now I got your point. you are right. I will update the question in the direction of your feedback.

Comment: I accept your feedback as answer because it helped me to figure out the problem and thanks for providing the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution and want to post here for others who have the same problem.

If you change this code

```
List<Event> list;
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var dbQuery = db.Set<Event>();
    dbQuery.Include(x => x.Location);
    list = dbQuery.ToList();
}
```

into

```
List<Event> list;
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var dbQuery = db.Set<Event>();
    dbQuery.Include(x => x.Location).Load();
    list = dbQuery.ToList();
}
```

then it works.

But I am not sure if it is the optimal way of dealing with problem.

Comment: Using List() method, cause immediately load data from database, and hit the performance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592911.aspx

Comment: do you mean Load() method?

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean Load() method.